# How to include a js Library within a CakePHP Plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, include

can anyone tell me how to include a js Library within a CakePHP Plugin ? 
In the root app/ folder I can do it in the Config/assets.php but where do I include it in a Plugin ?

The Library which I want to include is located in /app/Plugin/MyModule/webtoor/js/lib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use blocks for scripts and CSS files. More info here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files

```
Short answer:
// in your view
$this->Html->script('/pluginName/js/lib/whatever', array('block' => 'scriptBottom'));

// in your layout
echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom');
```

This should do the trick.